# mips-openwrt-linux-gdb error during simulation

Tags: c, linux, gdb, mips, openwrt

I am trying to build a positioning server so I have to write an application on several routers that use openwrt as OS for this purpose. I have installed all the cross-compile tools for MIPS architecture (gcc, ld, gdb).

After compilation, when I want to debug my program with GDB, I can't run it in simulator, I have this error:

```
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint -1.
```